# Is $f(x) = \frac{3x^2-|4x|+5}{x}$ even, odd, or neither

Tags: calculus

> Is $f(x) = \frac{3x^2-|4x|+5}{x}$ even, odd, or neither

For even: $f(-x) = f(x)$
For odd: $f(-x) = -f(x)$

$$f(-x) = \frac{3x^2-4|x|+5}{-x}$$

$$-f(x) = \frac{-3x^2 + 4|x| - 5}{x}$$

$f(-x) \neq f(x)$ and $f(-x) \neq -f(x)$

I thought $f(x)$ is neither but when looking at it's graph it looks like an odd function. Did I do anything wrong in the calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculate that
$$f(-x) = \frac{3x^2-4|x|+5}{-x}$$

$$-f(x) = \frac{-3x^2 + 4|x| - 5}{x}$$
and they are equal, so it's an odd function!

Comment: How are they equal?

Comment: $\frac{3x^2-4|x|+5}{-x}=-\frac{3x^2-4|x|+5}{x}=\frac{-3x^2 + 4|x| - 5}{x},$ isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here ,

$f(-x) = \frac{3x^2-4|  {x}|+5}{-x}$

$f(-x) = \frac{-3x^2+4|  {x}|-5}{x}$

$f(-x) = \frac{-3x^2+4|  {x}|-5}{x}=-f(x)$

They are eqauls